# Is there a coating substance that is very visible through a lens?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I'm trying to find a way to easily spot golf balls, and I was looking for some chemistry help. I was wondering if there is a substance that I could coat a golf ball in, that would be very visible through a specific type of lens?

Comment: A fluorescent paint, with perhaps additional UV illumination. If in sunlight, a few flashes might be needed, with UV-transmission filters on them.